# Incorrect data after merging with sqldf

Tags: r

I'm merging two dataframes with different times and after the merge is complete, all the records that get merged have a time (in column Date and EncounterDate) of either exactly `18:00:00` or `19:00:00` for some reason. How can I merge my two dataframes and get the accurate times from each dataframe?

```
df1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L), 
                      Full.Name = c( "John Smith", "Jack Peters", "Bob Brown", "Jane Doe", "Jackie Jane", "Sarah Brown", "Chloe Brown", "John Smith" ), 
                      Info = c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes"), 
                      EncounterID = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 13L), DateTime = c("1/2/21 00:00", "1/5/21 12:00", "1/1/21 1:31", "1/5/21 3:34", "5/9/21 5:33", "5/8/21 3:39", "12/12/21 2:30", "12/11/21 9:21"), 
                      Temp = c("100", "103", "104", "103", "101", "102", "103", "105"), 
 
                      misc = c("(null)", "no", "(null)", "(null)", "(null)","(null)", "(null)", "(null)" 
                                    )), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                      Full.Name = c("John Smith", "Jack Peters", "Bob Brown", "Jane Doe", "Jackie Jane", "Sarah Brown"), 
                      DOB = c("1/1/90", "1/10/90", "1/2/90", "2/20/80", "2/2/80", "12/2/80"), 
                      EncounterID = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), EncounterDate = c("1/1/21", "1/2/21", "1/1/21", "1/6/21", "5/7/21", "5/8/21"), 
                      Type = c("Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Care", "Out"), 
                      responses = c("(null)", "no", 
                                    "yes", "no", "no", "unsat")), 
                      
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -6L))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(sqldf)

df11 <- 
df1 %>% 
  separate(DateTime, c("Date", "Time"), sep=" ") %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_datetime(mdy(Date))) %>% 
  select(-Time) %>% 
  as_tibble()



df22 <-
df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate), mdy)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate), as_datetime)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df11 <- mutate(df11, Date_m30 = Date %m-% days(30), Date_p30 = Date %m+% days(30))
df11

df3 <- sqldf::sqldf("
    select df11.*, df22.DOB, df22.EncounterDate, df22.Type, df22.responses
    from df11
      left join df22 on df11.UserID = df22.UserID
        and df22.EncounterDate between df11.Date_m30 and df11.Date_p30") %>%
  select(-Date_m30, -Date_p30)
```

Comment: Simpler example: `sqldf::sqldf("select EncounterDate from df22")` - seems like `sqldf` is doing a timezone conversion.

Comment: Seems to be discussed [in this sqldf github issue](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/10)

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not handle timezones.  POSIXct objects are sent to SQLite as numbers (number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch) and are returned the same way.  sqldf has a heuristic to try to figure out what the intended class of the returned object is but the heuristic will only set the class and not other attributes.

There are several alternatives here:

1. Set your session to UTC so that there is no difference between it and the local time zones.  The main confusion is usually between local timezone and UTC so if they are the same it eliminates the confusion.    You can just leave your session that way or use `Sys.setenv(TZ = "")` to set it back after you have finished working with that data.

   ```
   Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
   sqldf("...")
   ```
2. Use Date class.  Actually, you should never use POSIXct in R if you can use Date.  There are many situations in R, not just  in sqldf, where timezones can give rise to subtle errors and you can avoid them all by using Date class.
3. Define a transformation passed to sqldf's method= argument which does what you want.

```
# set columns having Date in their name to POSIXct with UTC
fixct <- function(x) {
  ok <- grepl("Date", names(x))
  replace(x, ok, 
    lapply(x[ok], structure, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"))
}
sqldf("select EncounterDate from df22", method = fixct)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please edit the bottom of your post and add the addition(s) onto my code. I have trouble understanding  where to put either of the options you listed (1 and 2). I tried adding `Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")` before my `df3 <- sqldf::sqldf("...)` line and the time just disappeared.

Comment: How do I know/check if the times are correct when it's disappeared?

Comment: But I don't see any time in the final merge, not even the times that aren't 00:00

Comment: All the times in df11 and df22 in the question are 00:00:00.  What you are seeing is just the difference in how data frames and tibbles are displayed.    If the times are all 00:00:00 then data frames don't display them but tibbles do.  Convert any data frame to tibble if you want to force the 00:00:00 times to appear.

Comment: I understand. df1 has times that aren't 00:00 though. I'd like to retain those times and get them to show up in df3.

Comment: All the inputs to the sqldf statement in the question have 00:00:00 times so the outputs are necessarily 00:00:00 times as well.  If you actually had something with times that are not 00:00:00, which you don't, then you would see them.  Try: `d <- data.frame(x = Sys.time()); sqldf("select x from d")`

Comment: In df1, I have times that are `00:00, 12:00, 1:31, 3:34,...` in the DateTime column. They disappeared in df11. How can I make them appear in df11?

Comment: With lubridate `mdy_hm(df1$DateTime)` or if your session is not set to UTC and you want to specify that then `mdy_hm(df1$DateTime, tz = "UTC")`